# In Big Sur on a 2020 mini, is there a way to change the initial 'user list' screen background?

Tags: screen, user-account

I have been told by Apple that it is impossible to remove or change the background of the initial screen which lists 'users'.   Is this true?

I'm talking about the cheap, garish, brightly coloured abstract image.

How can I change this background image?

Comment: It‘s probably stored in /System somewhere, so changing it is tricky/close to impossible, and would need to be redone after each macOS update. Not sure it‘s worth the effort, the only time most users see that screen is after a reboot.

Comment: You'd have to appropriately disable **System Integrity Protection** to break the cryptographically signed read-only `/` _volume_ and delete `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Big Sur Graphic.heic`, however, if you have **File Vault** enabled you'll not be able to use it after breaking the seal. Frankly, I'd learn to live with it, because there may be additions issues after breaking the seal aside from havinge to redo it after every **macOS** update.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, you're probably both right.  I went as deep as I dared but had forgotten that, yes it would all have to be redone after each MacOS update.